# Is it suitable to save to store timestamp for each login in mongodb Array using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to store timestamp for each login in the array in mongodb using mongoose.so my question will it cause problem in future as the array size will increase with time.
i need your suggestion what approach should i use to save login timestamp for each login attempt in mongodb using mongoose.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MongoDB Limits and Thresholds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/):

> The maximum BSON document size is **16 megabytes**.

And as [BSON Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) states:

> BSON has a special timestamp type for internal MongoDB use and is not associated with the regular Date type. This internal timestamp type is a **64 bit** value

Let's do some calculation here:

```
16 MB = 1.28e+8 Bit = 64 Bit * 2e+6
```

So theoretically, the maximum length of timestamp array that can be stored in a MongoDB document is nearly 2,000,000.

This is fairly large enough for regular users who are going to login less than 10 times a day.

If a regular user logs in ten times a day for ten years, the array size will be:

```
10 * 365 * 10 = 36,500
```

which is very small to the theoretical limit and MongoDB can handle it without any problem.

Suppose a malicious user sent login request 10,000 times per second.

```
2,000,000(s) / 10,000 = 200(s) < 4(min)
```

Your document will exceed its size limit in less than a few minutes. Document update will fail after that, and the account cannot be used anymore. In other words, this approach is very vulnerable to DDoS and Brutal force attacks. Your database will be full of junk data.

Suggestion:

- Set a limit for the array size. In other words, store only last 10 (or more, if not thousands) login attempts. If you want to track login fail attempts, just count failed attempts and if the count exceeds a threshold, do something righteous.
- If you really need to store all login attempts, consider creating a new collection which will store all login attempts. However, you may want to set some limit to this too.
- If your server can handle rate limits ([429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)) correctly and you're sure of it, storing all login attempts in nested array can also be considered because the array limit is fairly large.